# How to migrate funambol from one machine to another?

Tags: data-migration, funambol

I want to set up my funambol server on a new machine. How can I migrate the database? Just copy the DB files? Which files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out: Only the Hypersonic DB file<sup>1</sup> needs to be copied to the new machine (in this case the old machine run funambol 9 and the new funambol 10):

```
$FUNAMBOLHOME/tools/hypersonic/data/funambol.script
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>technically it is not a DB file, but a collection of sql commands to restore the last state of the DB because hypersonic is a in-memory-DB</sub>